# Cambiar el tema del activity desde un fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Necesito que cambie el tema de mi MainActivity al entrar en un Fragment

HomeFragment.java

```
getActivity().setTheme(R.style.SoonticketThemeMain);
```

Hasta ahora eso no me ha funcionado

Esta es mi Activity

```
package com.soonticket.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.soonticket.R;
import com.soonticket.fragments.Home;
import com.soonticket.fragments.Profile;
import com.soonticket.util.CustomTypefaceSpan;
import com.soonticket.util.FontChangeCrawler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences prefs = null;
    Menu ActivityMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getAssets(), "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
        fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_main_view);
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);

        ActivityMenu = navigationView.getMenu();

        for (int i = 0; i < ActivityMenu.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem mi = ActivityMenu.getItem(i);

            //for aapplying a font to subMenu ...
            SubMenu subMenu = mi.getSubMenu();
            if (subMenu != null && subMenu.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < subMenu.size(); j++) {
                    MenuItem subMenuItem = subMenu.getItem(j);
                    applyFontToMenuItem(subMenuItem);
                }
            }

            //the method we have create in activity
            applyFontToMenuItem(mi);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, new Home()).commit();
        }
    }

    private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/segoeui.ttf");
        SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
        mNewTitle.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_main_view);
        ActivityMenu = navigationView.getMenu();

        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_account:
                fragmentClass = Profile.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_favorites:
                Toast.makeText(this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

            // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment).commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        // Close the navigation drawer
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void openDrawer() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

Y este es mi fragmento

```
package com.soonticket.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.soonticket.R;
import com.soonticket.activity.MainActivity;
import com.soonticket.util.FontChangeCrawler;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    RelativeLayout DrawerButtonHome;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        FontChangeCrawler fontChangeScrollToolbar = new FontChangeCrawler(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/r_medium.ttf");
        fontChangeScrollToolbar.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_toolbar));

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        DrawerButtonHome = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_button_home);
        DrawerButtonHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).openDrawer();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Abel Enoc, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** , saludos!

Comment: Agrega tu clase completa por favor , además comenta si tienes definición de tema en tu Activity o application en el AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Ya agregé parte de mi código espero que me puedan ayudar con esto, llevo días investigando pero casi nadie tiene respuesta, lo último que leí es que se puede hacer llamando setTheme(R.style.theme) justo antes de que se cree la instancia de la actividad setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

Comment: el fragmento pertenece a la actividad ? si es asi por que no cambias el color a cada fragment que contiene la actividad ...

Answer (score 0):

Técnicamente no se puede cambiar un tema de una actividad ya creada. Pero no todo esta perdido ya que existe una forma de cambiar el "tema".

hay una forma llamada "***Pocket***".

**¿ Como se hace y como funciona ?**

Basicamente consite en :

```
Base Color_1 +  Color intermedio = Theme Color_1

Base Color_2 +  Color intermedio = Theme Color_2
```

Tenga en cuenta que el color medio es el mismo que el color base, debe colocarlo en la ventana que contiene la instancia de su aplicación, algo como esto :

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(isLight ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK));
```

*Por lo tanto, cuando se combina con un color intermedio, le da dos temas diferentes.*

Si quieres un ejemplo y explicación mas detalla revisa [aquí](http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/runtime-theme-change/). (contenido en ingles)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Ashley G., pero creo que no me comprendiste o no me expliqué bien, lo que pasa es que quiero cambiar el "Tema" en si no los colores de fondo o del toolbar, porque tiene propiedades difrentes en cada tema, por eso lo quiero cambiar

Comment: Es que no puedes cambiar el tema de una actividad ya creada, y esta es la mejor solucion, en si no es un cambio de tema, es un cambio de colores que hacen parecer un cambio de tema. pero para cambiar el tema debes destruir la actividad y volver a crearla @AbelEnocRodríguez Tal vez si vemos el problema desde otro punto de vista podremos buscar una solucion ...

Comment: ¿Estás segura que no hay otra forma?, que mal, bueno, cosas de Android debería una forma de redeclarar esto en tiempo de ejecución, he visto apps que lo hacen...

Comment: Mi respuesta lo hace en tiempo de ejecución ... sin embargo no tengo en conocimiento otra forma mas simple e eficaz.  @AbelEnocRodríguez

Comment: Esta bien, muchas gracias, entraré en memoria para hacer esto, pero es tedioso